# How to fix: "Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3" on Ryzen CPU with Hyper-V and Hypervisor Platform enabled?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I´ve created an AVD basen on Pixel 2 and Android PIE on my AMD Ryzen system with Hyper-V and Hypervisior Platform enabled. If i press start AVD i get the lots of errors.

I´ve tried different PIE images (like x86 and other) and reinstalling Hyper-V and Hypervisor Platform.
I´ve also tried it without Hyper-V installed, but nothing worked for me.

```
17:40   Emulator: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to emulate MMIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 2 (InternalEmulationFailure )

17:40   Emulator: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: whpx_vcpu { emulator=000000001fc93300, window_registered=false, interruptable=true, tpr=0, apic_base=fee00900, interruption_pending=false }

17:40   Emulator: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHV_MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTEXT { Instruction={ size=16, bytes='A1 F0 00 E0 FE 80 CC 01 A3 F0 00 E0 FE C7 05 50 ' }, AccessInfo={ AccessType=0, GpaUnmapped=1, GvaValid=0, AsUINT32=4 }, Gpa=fee000f0, Gva=0 }

17:40   Emulator: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor

17:40   Emulator: Warning: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread ((null):0, (null))

17:40   Emulator: Warning: QMutex: destroying locked mutex ((null):0, (null))

17:40   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3
```

Does someone know how to fix those errors?

Comment: Hyper-V with Android emulators is very tricky yet, with many issues. Look at [this](https://montemagno.com/android-emulators-on-hyper-v-are-pretty-awesome/)